# Intel Open GL being broken with some distros

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, opengl

I've tried MANY, many distros at this point. But Ubuntu is by far my favorite. Just vanilla Ubuntu. My main problem is, is that some distros just refuse to work with OpenGL. Minecraft, TF2 and all launch fine, however polygons are invisible/visibly broken. I have provided glxgears, and other such utilities. I don't understand why some distros break this and why some do. Examples of working ones include Elementary OS, Debian, SteamOS, and some other small ones. Ubuntu distros however come across problems. [Output of glxgears, Visible polygons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ9Jo.png)

I will provide any extra information I can gather.

Device specs listed here.

- Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (Supports OpenGl 4 on Windows, is only 3 on ubuntu)
- Mesa Utils DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics (BYT)
- 3.0 Mesa 21.0.3
- Intel Celeron CPUJ1900 @ 1.99GHz

There's no slowing of anything, as others have reported. There are no issues with windows or anything. It appears that OpenGL3D just doesn't function properly. Help updating or solving issues would be greatly appreciated.

Is there a way to either fix OpenGL, or attempt to replace it to solve the problem?

Comment: ask ubuntu is a Q&A resource on the official ubuntu os and flavours. I don't see a question here.

Comment: Your provided details is of no use as it's missing all details. I QA-test software and personally find almost no differences between Debian, Ubuntu, OpenSuSE, Fedora, .... outside of the fact that they all take from the various *streams* at different times and have different software stacks. Of those my *tumbleweed* is usually the *latest* but without version detail my prior mention of opensuse was useless (ie. opensuse told you nothing; the version being tumbleweed did).  Were you comparing Debian Sid? Bullseye? or what? with what release of Ubuntu?? ie. not distro but the stack is key